# Emit map and mirror map? How can I texture emission and reflection?

Tags: texturing

How can I make the light affect other things from the emit map? Also a mirror map? I want a part of the wall that shows reflection of a mirror.

EDIT

I'm so confused. I'm in the cycles render now, and when I try to paint a mirror, it repeats..

[image]

Comment: what render engine are you using?

Comment: I was just told I need cycles to do this, so I switched to cycles today. However, I'm trying to paint and in cycles it starts repeating the paint on other areas.

Comment: Theres a picture in the post now

Answer (score 0):

[image]I tried a simple test: I created a 600x200 pixel png file, with the left half pure black and the right half pure white. Created a new emission material in Cycles and set the color to 'Image Texture', then loaded the png image as the texture. I placed the material on a quad and set that quad perpendicular to a flat surface and rendered. The half textured with white acted exactly like a bright light, shining white light over my flat surface. The half textured in black emitted no apparent light. Looks to me like it just works.

The blend for this texture emission can be found here: [image]

The partial mirror is achievable by using a glossy BDSF shader with another UV-mapped texture feeding the 'Roughness' variable. I updated the blend to use this textured mirroring node setup. You can find it here: [image]

Comment: Ok does that use node editors? If so can you point me in the right direction to learn the node editor?

Comment: I'm at work now so I could only post a quick answer. I'll be home a bit later and can upload screenshots and even a sample blend file. To your question, yes, the mirror thing would be done with a simple Node setup. The emission texture thing does not require knowing anything about nodes to put it together.

Comment: Ok thanks I await a reply with a blend demonstration

Comment: Hi again I was wondering what I did wrong. I got an emit working, but I made a 4x4px checkerboard picture, and applied it with nodes but afterwards, the following picture that is now in the question happened